# Future<int> not able to get data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I am trying to get the length of a collection in Firebase using Flutter. I have a profile page that loads how many hikes you have done from a database, but I keep getting a `Future<int>` when I print the variable. How do I solve this problem?

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _ProfilePage createState() => new _ProfilePage();
}

int doneHikes;
Database temp = new Database();

class _ProfilePage extends State<ProfilePage> {

@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _numOfDoneHikes();
}

Future<void> _numOfDoneHikes() async{
  var asyncResult = await temp.numOfDoneHikes();
  setState(() => doneHikes = asyncResult);
  print(doneHikes);

}
```

`numOfDoneHikes` function in the Database object:

```
Future<int> numOfDoneHikes() async {
  return Firestore.instance.collection(globalUserName)
    .document("Done Hikes").collection("Hike List").snapshots().length;
}
```

With this code, I keep getting `doneHikes` printing

```
instance of Future<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use await:

```dart
Future<int> numOfDoneHikes() async {
  return await Firestore.instance.collection(globalUserName)
    .document("Done Hikes").collection("Hike List").snapshots().length;
}
```

in fact, you don't even need await, you can do this instead:

```dart
Future<int> numOfDoneHikes() {
  return Firestore.instance.collection(globalUserName)
    .document("Done Hikes").collection("Hike List").snapshots().length;
}
```